# log4j exception handling problem

Tags: java, exception, log4j

I have a class which initializes my log4j. This code will never print or exit, I dont understand why.

```
public class MyLog
{

   private static Logger log;

   static
   {
      log = Logger.getRootLogger();
      try
      {
            PropertyConfigurator.configure("somefileNameWhichDoesNotExist");
      }
      catch(Exception t)
      {
            System.out.println("oops logging cant be set, lets exit");
            System.exit(0);
      }
```

Comment: You sure an exception is thrown ?

Comment: og4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
 at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:316)
 at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:342)
+log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (root).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: yep, in fact the whole point was to get an exception from this =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you assume that an exception will be thrown when the file doesn't exist? I just had a quick look at the API docs, and they don't say anything about the handling of missing files - so it's just as likely that the condition would just be ignored.

---

EDIT: just read your additional comments, so that's not the case.

Make sure that the static block is actually executing.

---

EDIT: PropertyConfigurator is catching the exception, and handling it internally. That's why you don't see the exception.  [See the source - lines 370-380](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/tags/v1_2_16/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.java?view=markup).

Comment: java will throw an exception somewhere deep deep down for sure. i know this. because no matter what they will use they will use java.lang and that will say NO FILE! exception and log4j prints a stack trace which has the exception. the only problem is I can't handle this myself and say kill the thread or something.

Comment: i checked the static block is executed.

Comment: So you're saying that a stack trace is printed, but the exception is never thrown to your code? This would mean that Log4J is catching the exception inside its own code.

Comment: Mike, yea Thread.currentThread().interrupt();. I guess I'm going to have code around this in my main thread. TY!

Answer (score 1):

[PropertyConfigurator#configure(String configFilename)](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#configure%28java.lang.String%29) does not throw any checked [Exception](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html), therefore there is never anything to catch with `catch(Exception t)`. Check the ApiDoc, because there has to be a declared Exception in the throws-clause, when you want to catch Exception.

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I've checked. No exception was thrown, but yet stdout printed an exception. Naturally I wanted to capture it, right?

Comment: I guess the exception was printed to `System.err`, not to `System.out`. Nevertheless you can never catch a `java.lang.Exception` if it is not declared in the throws-clause. (despite of bytecode-manipulations)

Answer (score 1):

Could you tell me, have found the answer to the question?
It will be very useful for me.

My solution is:

```
try
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFilePath));
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

May be you have a better one?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the configure method is throwing an Error?

Change your code to catch a java.lang.Throwable (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) instead of Exception.

Comment: I did both actually, Catch(Throwable t){} followed by catch(Exception e) {} AND NEITHER of them got executed.